# Checkbox toggle behavior is reverse of what is expected?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

At [this site](http://otiwebapps.appspot.com/) there is a 'Cholera facilities"checkbox for triggering the display of a map layer.

The problem is how the checkbox behaves. It is reverse what I expect-- it triggers upon being *unchecked*, rather than *checked*?

```
<div><input  type="checkbox" id="cholera_control" name="cholera_control" />
<label for="cholera_control">Cholera Facilities</label></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reverse the `if` with the `else`.

Instead of:

```
if (showCholera) {
    kmlLayerCTF.setMap(null);
} else {
    kmlLayerCTF.setMap(map);
}
```

do:

```
if (showCholera) {
    kmlLayerCTF.setMap(map);
} else {
    kmlLayerCTF.setMap(null);
}
```

This is happening because your initial value is `false`.

```
var showCholera = false;
```

...then you're reversing it *before* the `if()` statement:

```
showCholera = !showCholera;
```

...so when the `if()` runs, `showCholera` is `true`, and the `if` is executed instead of the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cholera_control" name="cholera_control" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mc-cb" id="mc-cb">
```

to:

```
<input type="checkbox" check="checked" id="cholera_control" name="cholera_control" />
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="mc-cb" id="mc-cb">
```